# Не компилируется файл .py в .exe

Tags: python

Всем привет

у меня имеется python3.10.8, библиотеки установленные:

```
et-xmlfile      1.1.0   
numpy           1.24.1  
opencv-python   4.5.4.58    
openpyxl        3.0.10  
pip             22.3.1
pyzbar          0.1.9
setuptools      57.0.0
wheel           0.36.2
```

Версия конвертора auto-py-to-exe 2.26.1

Ошибка после конвертации

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "inventary.py", line 9, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'
```

Пробовал последнюю версию opencv-python, та же ошибка, помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно у вас установлено несколько версий питона рядом, и на той, которую вы пытаетесь использовать этот модуль действительно не установлен

Comment: Добавлю от себя, еще может быть, что сам проект в виртуальном окружении, а компилирование происходит вне него, ли наоборот

Comment: Спасибо, сработало, запускал  pyinstaller из той среды, в которой писал код

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте модуль pyinstaller.

Установка:

```
    pip install pyinstaller
```

Затем перейдите в папку, где лежит ваш .py файл, и пропишите в консоли:

```
    pyinstaller --onefile <имя_вашего_файла>.py
```

Потом немного ждём, и в папке с проектом появляется две папки: build и dist, а также файл <имя_вашего_файла>.spec.

Зайдите в папку dist, где и будет лежать .exe файл. Можно перенести этот файл в другую папку, все будет работать.